# Google charts show all values on v-Axis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have been attempting to get a google chart to show each and every specified value labeled along the vAxis.

Currently, the most I can can get it to show is a label for every other tick.   It seems like there should be a way to get around this.

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

I have the vAxis options set like this:

```
            vAxis: {

                ticks: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
                direction: -1,
                minValue: 0,
                maxValue:20,
                showTextEvery:1


            }
```

What I need is for it to label each and every row, meaning 1,2,3,4,5, etc... instead of just 1,3,5,9....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the values are specified in the `vAxis.ticks` option and still do not appear,
then you will need to either increase the height of the chart and / or chart area...

```
height
chartArea.height
```

or decrease the font size...

```
vAxis.textStyle.fontSize
```